# Function to bring individual folds into global environment after caret::createFolds

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I would like to bring individual folds into the global environment after using `caret::createFolds`. A working example is below.

```
# Load libraries 

library(tibble)
library(caret)


# Set the seed so example is reproducible     

set.seed(123)


# Create example data set

df1 <- tibble(id      = seq(1, 100, by = 1),
              gender  = as.factor(rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = 0.50)),
              working = as.factor(rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = 0.40)),
              pweight = sample(50:500, 100,  replace   = TRUE))

# Create 5 folds

folds <- createFolds(df1$id, k = 5)
```

This creates 5 data sets with 20 observations each, just as expected. What I would like to do now is bring each of these data sets into the global environment. I can do it individually with the following commands:

```
fold1 <- df1[folds[[1]], ]
fold2 <- df1[folds[[2]], ]
fold3 <- df1[folds[[3]], ]
fold4 <- df1[folds[[4]], ]
fold5 <- df1[folds[[5]], ]
```

But I would like to write a function or loop to do this more concisely. In my real-world example, I have 20 folds, so it is quite a bit of code. I would like the folds to be names sequentially (i.e., fold1, fold2, fold3, etc).

I was trying `list2env(folds, envir = .GlobalEnv)`, but that doesn't bring the individual data sets into the global environment.

I am still learning how to best use functions, so any explanation would also be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the logic of put all folds in to .GlobalEnv? AFAIK, it is easier for potential downstream analysis in the current form. Anyway, you can do it with `list2env(lapply(folds, function(x) df1[x, ]), .GlobalEnv)`.

Comment: I want to examine the individual data sets to get a feel for how k-fold cross-validation works (I understand it conceptually, but it is always nice to actually see the individual data sets split up). I agree the current form is more conducive for training and testing downstream. But when I was writing the code to bring them in individually, I thought there must be a better way! A teachable moment if you will.